# XForms - copy child nodes from one instance to another

Tags: xml, xslt, orbeon, xforms

My problem is that I have a section in my main instance as such:

```
 <DocumentBody>
    :     :    :
    <SectionToBeUpdated />
    :     :    :
 </DocumentBody>
```

And also an updated "SectionToBeUpdated" in a different instance as such:

```
   <SectionToBeUpdated>
       <Section />
       <Section />
       <Section />
   </SectionToBeUpdated>
```

The behaviour I require is that all child elements of SectionToBeUpdated in the main instance are removed and replaced with the child elements of SectionToBeUpdated in the other instance.

Each time I try I get the whole SectionToBeUpdated section nested inside the existing SectionToBeUpdated section in the main instance.

I hope that's understandable?
TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your main instance id is `main-instance`, and your other instance with `<SectionToBeUpdated>` as the root element is `section-template`, the following actions should do it:

```
<xf:delete
    ref="instance('main-instance')/SectionToBeUpdated/*"/>
<xf:insert
    context="instance('main-instance')/SectionToBeUpdated"
    origin="instance('section-template')/SectionToBeUpdated/*"/>
```